# MySQL, вложенный JOIN. Как несколько раз смотреть в одну и ту же таблицу в одном запросе?

Tags: mysql, join

У меня есть 2 таблицы: в одной хранятся названия единиц измерения, а в другой - параметры фасовки товара.

**packing_type**
mass
mass_unit_id
volume
volume_unit_id

**unit_type**
id
title
short_title

Допустим, я хочу, чтобы в результате у меня получилась таблица, в которой первые столбцы содержат информацию:

Масса      Ед. массы      Объём       Ед.объёма
1000    |      г       |     975    |     мл

Получается, что мне надо 2 раза заглянуть в таблицу unit_type и получить оттуда соответствующие единицы измерения для массы и для объёма.

Если написать такой запрос

```
SELECT  `product_unit`.`mass` AS 'Масса'
        , `unit_type`.`short_title` AS 'Ед. массы'
        , `product_unit`.`volume` AS 'Объём'
        , `unit_type`.`short_title` AS 'Ед. объёма'
FROM    `product_unit`
LEFT JOIN `unit_type` ON `product_unit`.`mass_unit_id` = `unit_type`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `unit_type` AS `utv` ON `product_unit`.`volume_unit_id` = `utv`.`id`;
```

то получится:

Масса      Ед. массы      Объём       Ед.объёма
1000    |      г       |     975    |     г

Как быть?

Comment: Это никакой не вложенный джойн, это два джойна на одну таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

Использовала псевдонимы для таблицы unit_type.
Заработало.

```
SELECT 
    product_unit.mass AS 'Масса' , 
    u1.short_title AS 'Ед. массы' , 
    product_unit.volume AS 'Объём' , 
    u2.short_title AS 'Ед. объёма' 
FROM    product_unit 
LEFT JOIN unit_type AS u1 ON product_unit.mass_unit_id = u1.id 
LEFT JOIN unit_type AS u2 ON product_unit.volume_unit_id = u2.id;
```